# Default attribute in model field

Tags: django, django-models

I have model like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
   some_field = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='bbb')
```

If I create new object like this:

```
a1 = A()
a2 = A(some_field="ccc")
print "a1 {}".format(a1.some_field)
print "a2 {}".format(a2.some_field)
```

should I get

> a1 bbb
>
> a2 ccc

?

Comment: I get error, that some_field is required. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, but this does not look like what you are attempting to do from the error you mention "some_field is required". If you want to allow a form to accept blank values, you have to set `some_field` to accept blank values. You need to add [`blank=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank) to your field constructor so that the validation will pass and the default value will be used in the database.

You also never save those objects so they aren't actually created in the database.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you're trying to do. You don't need to add `blank=True` if you do not intend to use the Model field in a form. `default` value will be enough to persist the field in the database with that value if none is given.

On the other side, if you intend to use the field inside the model form, then you will need to add `blank=True` to your model or `required=False` to the field in the model.

Now related to your question, yes. That's exactly what you should get if you try to do that.

Comment: Models go through validation themselves, not just when used in ModelForms. The forms use these validations when `is_valid` is called. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) for more information.

Comment: I see, but I just tested the example in the shell without the blank attribute and it allowed me to save it to the db, just with the default. But without the blank, the `ModelForm` didn't validate. That's when I searched the doc form `Models` and saw this: "Note that this is different than null. null is purely database-related, whereas blank is validation-related. If a field has blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a field has blank=False, the field will be required."

Comment: I see what you mean, but he mentioned that he is getting a validation error so I was focusing on form validation. I will clarify that in my answer.